# Informatica for special character

Tags: oracle, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have an xml file 
my tag is like

```
<'vin'>'data'<'/vin'>
```

I need to find posotion of `<'/vin'>` using

Informatica Expression transformation

Pleae help.

Comment: What does it have to do with Oracle? The title mentions some _special character_ - why? Did you try to use `INSTR`? http://informaticareference.wordpress.com/2012/03/14/instr/

Answer (score 1):

Use the CHR function with the ASCII code 39 to replace the single quotes like below:

```
INSTR(INPUT_PORT,'<'||chr(39)||'/vin'||chr(39)||'>')
```